# Spring + Mockito injection not working

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, mockito, spring-boot

I'm new with Spring and Mockito testing. I couldn't find answer to my problem on stackoverflow.

I have the following classes:

```
@EnableScheduling
@Service
public class ServiceEx {

    private Queue<Object> tasks = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();

    public void addItem(Object task) {
        tasks.add(task);
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000)
    public void executePendingTask() {
        tasks.remove();
    }

    public void drop() {
        tasks.clear();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return tasks.isEmpty();
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/drop")
public class ControllerEx {

    private ServiceEx service;

    @Inject
    public ControllerEx(ServiceEx service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String dropTasks(Model model) {
        service.drop();
        return "redirect:/home";
    }

}
```

And my testing class looks like :

```
public class ControllerTest {

    @Inject
    private ServiceEx service;

    @InjectMocks
    private ControllerEx controller;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        service.add(task1);
        service.add(task2);
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/drop")).andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection());
        assertTrue(service.isEmpty());
    }

}
```

My problem is that service is null in both ControlleEx and ControllerTest and i don't want to mock it. I tried several annotations, but didn't find which one to use.

What have i done wrong?

Comment: There is nothing bootstrapping your services. You don't have mocks in your test so there is nothing to mock. So not sure why you are even using Mockito here.

Comment: Yes, it's a simplified example of my real class, i'm mocking others classes. Mocked classes are successfully instancied but service is not.

Comment: As I stated in your test class I don't see something that ties it to Spring so not sure how it should instantiate classes. It will also not inject mocks into the controller as there won't be a controller. Can you modify your post to better reflect your case as at the moment it doesn't.

Comment: I edited my post, also I'm using spring boot framework.

Comment: There is nothing in your test case that is bootstrapping spring there are is `@RunWith`, there is also no `@ContextConfiguration` or `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code you seem to be mixing unit tests with integration tests.

MockMvc is usually used to do integration tests starting at the controller level. this means that you need a configured and started applicationContext to successfully use that. If that's what this test class is supposed to do then I don't see the use of Mocks, unless you wire them in the application context, your controller won't use them.

If you want to do integration testing, but want to Mock or stub out certain functionality (which in my opinion should only be done because of dependencies on external systems) you should think about wiring some stubs in your applicationContext for this test instead of trying to use Mockito for this.

Also keep in mind that by default, the applicationContext is re-used to run all your tests, which could mean that stubbing for one test could affect an other.